# Django Custom User Model EmailField not Validated

Tags: python, django, validation, python-3.x, django-models

I am not sure either I am doing / expecting something wrong or there a issue in validating EmailField when you override User Model in Django.
Basically what I wanted was to remove username and make email address username (or unique identifier), So I did override my user Model as,

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    # Plus all the remaining stuff / methods we need override
```

Now the problem is I can create user even with invalid email address, seems there is no validation happening on field level.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
User(email='iamnotemail', password='pass').save()
User.objects.get(email='ghjkl')
<CustomUser: ghjkl>
```

I also tried adding `field_clean` and also adding custom email validator to field but no luck.

Please help me if you have an idea / clue what is wrong with this.

Thanks

Note: I am using Django 1.9

Answer (score 1):

To validate model fields, do not save the instance directly.

Run `clean_fields()` and/or `full_clean()` on model before saving.

```
>>> u = User(username='foo', password='bar', email='foobar')
>>> u
<User: foo>
>>> u.clean_fields()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vikas/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1161, in clean_fields
    raise ValidationError(errors)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'email': ['Enter a valid email address.']}
>>> u.full_clean()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vikas/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1136, in full_clean
    raise ValidationError(errors)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'email': ['Enter a valid email address.']}
>>>
```

Read about Model field validation @ [django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)

Also, it is a *very* bad idea to save user instances like this. Always use `create_user()` method to create users.